# Finding matches from 2 ranges and replacing matches with a specific value, any way to optimize?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the sample sheet.
From this

```
1    Search area       Bounty list  Bullet      
2      a    i   z       a   b   c   abc
3      e    b   d       d   e   f   def
4      y    f   h       g   h   i   ghi
5                               
6      1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8
7                Column #
```

To this

```
1    Search area          Bounty list   Bullet      
2      abc  ghi z         a   b   c     abc
3      def  abc def       d   e   f     def
4      y    def ghi       g   h   i     ghi
5                               
6       1    2   3   4    5   6   7      8
7                Column #
```

It will take a value "bounty" from the "bounty list" starting from (2,5) or "a", search around the "Search Area" in a sequence, from a, i, z, e, b, d, y, f, h. Then if it finds a cell or multiple cells that equals the value of "bounty", then it will place the value of "bullet" from column 8 on the current "bounty" row to those cells. The process will repeat in the sequence of a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i on the "bounty list". Both process moves to the left, and down.

```
function menuItem1()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var target = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  for (var BountyRow = 2; BountyRow<target.length; BountyRow++)//switching rows in bounty list//
  {
    var bullet = sheet.getRange(BountyRow, 8).getValue(); //cell value to paste on targets// 
    for (var BountyColumn = 5; BountyColumn<8; BountyColumn++) //switching columns in bounty list//
    {
    var bounty = sheet.getRange(BountyRow, BountyColumn).getValue();  // cell value to search for//
    if (bounty !=0)
      {
        for (var SearchRow = 1; SearchRow<target.length; SearchRow++) //switching row on search area//
        {
          for(var SearchColumn = 0; SearchColumn<4;SearchColumn++)//switching column on search area//
          {

            if(target[SearchRow][SearchColumn] == bounty) //if search target is found//
            {
              var found = target[SearchRow][SearchColumn];
              sheet.getRange(SearchRow+1, SearchColumn+1).setValue(bullet);
              Logger.log((found)+ " in "+"row"+(SearchRow+1)+", column"+(SearchColumn+1));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It involves thousands of searches which always use more than a minute and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Welcome. The distinction between the "list on the right", and the "list on the left" is not clear. e.g. does the list on the right include column I, and what is the purpose of Column I anyway. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and edit your question to provide a less ambiguous explanation. Also please share your spreadsheets (less private or confidential information) and include an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In order to optimize your code you need to do two things:

1. Instead of using `getValue()` and `setValue()` for each cell (which makes you code slow)

   - retrieve all your bounty list and search are data once, with `getValues()`
   - assign the values to an array
   - replace matches within the the array
   - set the updated array values back into the range with `setValues()`
2. Make use of [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
   to find matches and replace them more efficiently

**Sample:**

```
function menuItem1(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var searchValues=sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-2+1,3).getValues();
  var bountyValues=sheet.getRange(2,5,lastRow-2+1,3).getValues();
  var bulletValues=sheet.getRange(2,8,lastRow-2+1,1).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i<bountyValues.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j<bountyValues[0].length; j++){
      if (bountyValues[i][j] !=0){        
        replaceValues(searchValues, bountyValues[i][j], bulletValues[i][0]);
      }
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-2+1,3).setValues(searchValues)
}
function replaceValues(search, bounty, bullet) {
  for(var k=0;k<search.length;k++){
    search[k]=search[k].map(function(search) {
      var regex=new RegExp("\\b"+bounty+"\\b","g");
      return search.toString().replace(regex, bullet);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the lastRow-2+1 vs lastRow-1 make a difference?

Comment: No. I was just to illustrate that the number of rows is equal to "last row-first row+1"